# Document compiles differently in different computers

Tags: compiling, texstudio, bold

I use a Latex template for my resume and it always worked great. I recently reinstalled TeXstudio in one of my computers and now the resume shows up all in bold, for no apparent reason. In Overleaf, it also compiles in bold. When I compile the exact same file on my older computer, it compiles as it should.

I'd appreciate any help in understanding how I can avoid the bold font. Thank you in advance.

Edit: I updated the code below, now it should be working. I also uploaded the resume.cls file in https://easyupload.io/7u4u3n

```
\documentclass{resume}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{
    \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
\name{\LARGE\textsc{Person X}} 
\vspace*{-0.75cm}
\address{\textit{Last updated: \monthyeardate\today}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.74\textwidth}
        Phone:  \\
    Email: \\
    Homepage:  \\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
    \begin{rSection}{Academic positions}
                {\bf University X} \hfill {2022 - }
        \\ Assistant Professor
    \end{rSection}
    \begin{rSection}{Education}
        {\bf University Y} \hfill {2015 - 2020}
        \\ PhD in Physics
    \end{rSection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the posted code produces the error `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end` from the misplaced `\\ ` also do not use `ucs` packge with current latex. Note texlive does not have a `resume.cls` you may have different versions on the two machines the log file will show versions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think something was moved when I copied-pasted the code. Now it should be fine. I also have uploaded the resume.cls file on: https://easyupload.io/7u4u3n .

Comment: It does! Thank you very much! I am sorry that I did not find this post myself